# PresentationButton didn't trigger action twice

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to present modally view and after dismissing present it once again.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                Text("hi")
                Text("hello")
                }
                .navigationBarItem(title: Text("Demo"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    PresentationButton(
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                            .imageScale(.large)
                            .accessibility(label: Text("User Profile"))
                            .padding(),
                        destination: Text("User Profile")
                    )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It triggers only during first tap. After dismissing destination view the tap on `PresentationButton` do nothing. Do someone have the solution for this?

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. It didn't work for me either. Hope, somebody(WWDC attendees) checks with Apple folks during SwiftUI labs..

Comment: @SMP Do u know should we fill issue somewhere?

Comment: Also had this issue. Even weirder, I had another button above my presentation button and after the first click of the presentation button, the Button above took over the presentation button's action.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this, can you or anyone confirm the OS you're on?  I'm curious if it's isolated to Mojave given the "Full working support" is only in Catalina

Comment: @apocolipse I have the issue on both platforms (catalina & mojave)

Comment: I have the same issue, even with the tutorial project downloaded from apple developer site. Definitely a bug

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a bug, here's a workaround:

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var showModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Group {
                Text("hi")
                Text("hello")
            }
            .navigationBarItem(title: Text("Demo"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: {
                    self.showModal = true
                }) {
                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                }
            )
            }.presentation(showModal ? Modal(Text("Hey"),
                                             onDismiss: { self.showModal = false }) : nil)
    }
}
```